# How to unit test an Android Bluetooth application?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-bluetooth

I am working on an Android Bluetooth application which needs to interact with the BluetoothAdapter, BluetoothDevice, and BluetoothProfile classes.

Suggestions as to what might be "best practice" to allow unit testing which is independent of physical device connections?

Thanks,
Zach

Answer (score 4):

Loose coupling and abstraction. Introduce interaces that represent *contract* of your bluetooth-interaction-feature and work with them. Components interacting with bluetooth will simply *talk* to this abstraction. This involves creating simple wrappers around `Bluetooth`-family classes and using them in your application while test setup uses *fakes* (eg. in memory devices or something auto-generated by mocking tools).

This way your high level business rules/policies (*application should send data via bluetooth interface*) will remain decoupled from low-level details (*bluetooth driver class provided by company x*).

Comment: is there any example of such implementation on internet?